# Create Hidden Windows file/folder from Linux

Tags: windows, linux, file, hidden, samba

Is it possible to create a file on a mounted SMB share that is hidden from Windows? The .(dot) prefix doesn't work in this case because that only works on Linux. Basically I'm looking for the same affect as using `attrib +h` on Windows, but under Linux.

Comment: Correction CIFS mounted share from a Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the executable-by-others bit in the file you want hidden. For example:

- rwxrwxrw- <-- The file will not be hidden
- rwxrwxrwx <-- HIDDEN

Hopefully that helps. If you want the Windows hidden attribute to apply to your Linux share, by the way, you'll have to set map hidden = yes in your samb.conf file.

Comment: This appears to apply when you host your file share from a Linux box, I have a file share mounted through CIFS in fstab that I'm trying to modify. Sorry, should have made that more clear in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Samba share currently looks like this in `smb.conf`:

```
[share-with-hidden-files]
  comment = this share shows all files when browsing it (doesn't work as expected)
  path = /some/where/on/the/linux/file/system
  browseable = yes
  [...more settings...]
```

Add one more line to it:

```
[share-with-hidden-files]
  comment = this share includes some hidden files
  path = /some/where/on/the/linux/file/system
  browseable = yes
  [...more settings...] 
  hide files = /firstfile.doc/secondfile.pdf/.*/*.xls/
```

The `hide files` instruction will turn all denoted files into invisible ones (but they are still accessible!). The DOS '*hidden*' attribute is applied to any files or directories which match.

In above example line 2 files are explicitely named (a .doc and a .pdf) to be hidden, as well as all 'dot'-files and all .xls files.

***Notes on using `hide files`:***

- file names are separated by '/'
- file names may contain spaces (but no '/')
- file names are case sensitive
- you may use '?' and '*' wildcards for filenames    -

Answer (score 0):

you can just use setmode filename +h