# Make a file/folder hidden under Windows while using a Linux distro

Tags: linux, windows, file-permissions

How can I make a file or folder I just created hidden (in Windows) while I am booted into Linux? Basically I'm dual booting linux and windows. I want to create a file/folder in my common data partition that I want to stay hidden in both Windows and Linux.

I will name it something like **.secret_stuff** so that it's hidden in Linux. Now how do I make sure that it is hidden under Windows?

**Related:**

This question is simillar to "[Create Hidden Windows file/folder from Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967865/create-hidden-windows-file-folder-from-linux?rq=1)" but that one is more about making it hidden under Samba share. In this thread I want to hide file/folder using Linux so that it is still hidden when I reboot into Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If the file system of data partition is FAT or NTFS, it is possible to set hidden attribute on files or folders. However info in OP is insufficient for getting a precise answer.

Comment: Yes it is a NTFS file system